# Add data to python

Tags: python

I have the following lists:

```
['4', 'H']['K', 'H']['6', 'H']['6', 'D']['4', 'H']['Q', 'C']['8', 'D']
```

Is it possible to import these into python without manually adding commas between each one?

I've tried assigning it to a variable like:

```
b = ['4', 'H']['K', 'H']['6', 'H']['6', 'D']['4', 'H']['Q', 'C']['8', 'D']
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: Right you are, it came from a "return JsonResponse" python command so I assumed it was.

Comment: @WereWithTheVipers provide a [mre]

Comment: @ggorlen you'd still be missing commas

Comment: @eyllanesc I thought that's what I did? If you throw b = ['4', 'H']['K', 'H']['6', 'H']['6', 'D']['4', 'H']['Q', 'C']['8', 'D'] into python and run it, it gives that error.

Comment: @WereWithTheVipers You say: *I have the following data coming from a webbserver response*, my requirement is that you provide the code with which you get that data.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign multiple lists to a single variable and that's not allowed
Try this.

Wrap all of the lists in another list so that you can place it inside the variable

```
b = [['4', 'H'],['K', 'H'],['6', 'H'],['6', 'D'],['4', 'H'],['Q', 'C'],['8', 'D']]
```

And to access it just do this.

```
b[0][0] // Output: 4
```

This is now called a multi-dimensional list

Comment: The problem I have is that in reality it's a much larger list than the one I described. If I put the commas in between manually, it loads in just fine. But I'm trying to create a script where I take the output from a response and process it with python, so it's not feasible for me to manually add the commas in each time.

Comment: Can you show the code on how you retrieved the data?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty messy return you're getting, but if you replace the middle `]` values with `],` wrap it all in a list, and swap the single quotes for doubles, you can parse it as JSON:

```
In [121]: s = "['4', 'H']['K', 'H']['6', 'H']['6', 'D']['4', 'H']['Q', 'C']['8', 'D']"

In [122]: json.loads('[{}]'.format(s.replace("]", "],").replace("'", '"')[:-1]))
Out[122]:
[['4', 'H'],
 ['K', 'H'],
 ['6', 'H'],
 ['6', 'D'],
 ['4', 'H'],
 ['Q', 'C'],
 ['8', 'D']]
```

Comment: Yeah, it's butt ugly I know. Turns out I just needed to place the double quotes at the beginning and end of the data to do what I wanted with it, I feel so silly. Thanks so much.